# Only allow S3 files on my site

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to allow s3 files only on my site. They should be able to download files from my site ony. Not from any other site. Please tell me how i can do that.

I tried bucket policy and cros configuration but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should describe your steps in detail and attach your CORS policy.

Answer (score 1):

You could restrict origin using  CORS headers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html  this would only block cross-site resources directly displayed or processed, not files to be downloaded

As a solution - make the S3 bucket private (not public) and your site can generate signed expiring (temporary) url for S3 resources 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html

there are multiple blogs and exampled just search for it

Answer (score 0):

You could code your Bucket Policy to [Restrict Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this can be faked so it is not a guaranteed method of controlling access.

If you *really* wish to control who can access your content, your application should verify the identity of the user (eg username/password) and then generate time-limited **Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URLs**. This is the way you would normally serve private content, such as personal photos and PDF files.